# Can't produce this font in CSS

Tags: css, fonts

[image]

The chrome extension I am using says it's using `'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;` but on my OSX Yosemite it produces as:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the link?

Comment: @Vishwanath Only if I had that in hTML format I'd not have asked it. It's a behance link: https://www.behance.net/gallery/32466989/Reddit-Re-Design

Comment: Have you tried running it through https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Comment: @Dom-TaphillStudios yes, it failed to recognize.

Comment: Post your question on Stack Exchange's Graphic Design site. Tag it with **Font-Identification**. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You will need to check to see if your font is installed in OSX..open a shell and type 'fc-list'..this should show you all fonts installed..if not then you can download it and add it to your css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Museo is the font you need https://typekit.com/fonts/museo - you will need to load it through typekit to use it on your page.

[image]

[Learn how to use typekit for web use.](http://help.typekit.com/customer/portal/articles/6780)

Comment: As long as you subscribe to at least one Adobe Creative Cloud service you are able to use any of the fonts on Typekit. Museo is avilable for download or web use.